# Magento 2: custom action di compile issue

Tags: magento2, reindex

I have created below code for the reindexing programmatically from a custom  url, bit i got the below error while running below code, please help me to solve out this issue.

```
<?php

namespace Codextblog\Customemail\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

   protected $processor;

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor $processor
    ) {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /* Regenerate indexes for all indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAll();

        /* Regenerate indexes for all invalid indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAllInvalid();
    }
}
```

And I got the below error while running the above code in my controller.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have using **__construct**, you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context`  and call parent class `__construct()`

```
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,   
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor $processor
) {
    $this->processor = $processor;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's work for me.